# Beginner: How do I run my package in other machine?

Tags: ros, package, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a package that I'm developing in my computer using catkin workspace. To test some network issues, I need run a node from this package in other machines. I read the tutorial "Running ROS across multiple machines" but I don't know how deploy or copy my package to the remote machine. The tutorial uses a "pre-instaled" package (rospy_tutorials). I think it's a common task and should be simple to do.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139731/beginner:-how-do-i-run-my-package-in-other-machine?/) by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this question and answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/138156/how-does-ros-execute-my-nodes-on-a-remote-machine/

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on 2014-03-13**:
Thanks a lot!
That's I was doing but I thought there was a more simple way to do it